# git cvsimport fails: Could not merge master into the current branch

Tags: git, migration, cvs

I'm trying to import a project which grew over several years in cvs. It has some branches for patch releases, tags and a head. 
This is the command which I'm using:

```
 git cvsimport -r cvs -k -d :pserver:<USERNAME>@cvs:/home/cvsroot <MODULNAME>
```

It worked perfectly some weeks ago. A few days ago a branch was created for the current release, where people still commit, and others already working on the head for the next milestone. This branch will be merged into the head later.

Momentarily the process fails with the following messages herein below:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
fatal: Can merge only exactly one commit into empty head
Could not merge master into the current branch.
```

What can be the reason? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by not importing the whole history which is dated back to 2006.
This is my procedure:

- Create a new git repository
- Touch a new file
- Add and commit that file with the date switch
- do the cvs import

Here are the commands involved:

```
mkdir project.cvs    
mkdir project.git    
cd project.git
git init
touch test
git add test
git commit -m "initial" --date="2010-01-01 00:00:00"
cd ../project.cvs
git cvsimport -o master -C ../project.git -k -d :pserver:<USERNAME>@cvs:/home/cvsroot <MODULENAME>
```

In my case it took a while, but as I changed back to the git repo, the history since 2010 was available.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this to work:

```
$ cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@example.org:/path/to/cvsroot login
$ git-cvsimport -v -a -i -k -d pserver:anonymous@example.org:/path/to/cvsroot -C <git_repository> <cvs_module>
```

Command line arguments are:

```
-v: verbose; report a lot of information about what's going on
-a: import all commits, not just recent ones
-i: import-only. don't mess with working directory
-k: 'kill keywords': no CVS keyword expansion (e.g. $Date$)
-d: root of cvs archive (you could also set CVSROOT if you really wanted to)
```